# can not access sql server developer sp1 ssis from ssms

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I am installing Sql server 2016 Sp1 developer on Azure VM Windows 2012 R2 datacenter. The database engine and analysis service (SSAS) are working proerpty however integration service (SSIS) is inaccessible even the service is running.

The services are running:
[image]

but I could not login from SSMS (run as Administrator). The message error is "The specified service does not exist as an installed service":
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On SQL2005, SSIS service doesn't do much - are you sure you need it?

This https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/279d724f-fb97-4d9a-ac6f-b0de4de8d0fb/ssis-port?forum=sqlintegrationservices says it runs on port 135 so I guess you haven't opened that port

On SQL 2016, SSIS service does even less. You don't use it. It's only there for backwards compatability. You use the SSIS catalog instead.

See here for info on creating the catalog

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471509(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: it is sql server developer 2016 sp1. I am running SSMS in the same machine with SSIS.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: perfect. Thanks Nick